# Get the most recently used date from two different tables with two different named columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I've two tables say `table 1` and `table 2`,

`table 1` has column names as `sno` and `useddate`
`table 2` has column names as `sno` and `recentlyuseddate`

I want to compare these two columns `useddate` and `recentlyusedate` and get the most recently used date.

These tables may have many entries but I need only ONE ENTRY (mostrecent) date after comparing these tables.

Comment: Sno is unique within the table?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MAX(useddate) AS mostrecent
FROM 
(SELECT useddate FROM Table1
UNION ALL
SELECT recentlyuseddate AS useddate FROM Table2) TheUnion
```

Comment: I want most recent date of all sno

Comment: Do you need the value of sno that goes with the mostrecent date?

Answer (score 0):

You can use unions for this

```
 SELECT MAX(col)
 FROM (SELECT col FROM TABLE_1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT col FROM TABLE_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have an index on the two dates in the two tables, I would go for:

```
select top 1 sno, useddate, which
from ((select top 1 sno, useddate, 'table1' as which from table1 order by useddate desc) union all
      (select top 1 sno, recentlyuseddate , 'table2' as which from table2 order by recentlyuseddate desc)
     )
order by useddate desc;
```

This version also tells you which table the date came from.

Comment: I want most recent date of all sno.

Comment: @user2459816 . . . That is easily accomplished by including `sno` in the `select` lists.  You can put as many columns as you like from the tables (so long as they align in the `union`).